# No table is created when excuted "python3 manage migrate"

Tags: python, django, model, migrate

python version: 3.6.4
django version: 3.1.7
db: sqlite3
my_app: robot
my_models: Check_Monitor_Task, Action_Manager, Questions_Answers_Task

Step1: models
Step2: python3 manager makemigrations

> Migrations for 'robot':
> robot/migrations/0001_initial.py
> - Create model Action_Manager
> - Create model Check_Monitor_Task
> - Create model Questions_Answers_Task

Step3: python3 manager migrate

> Operations to perform:
> Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, robot, sessions
> Running migrations:
> Applying robot.0001_initial... OK

Step4: confirm the tables
**There is record in django_migrations**

> sqlite> select * from django_migrations order by id desc limit 3;
> id|app|name|applied
> **25|robot|0001_initial|2022-05-11 17:33:16.780900**
> 18|sessions|0001_initial|2022-05-10 21:30:28.049031
> 17|auth|0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length|2022-05-10 21:30:27.985724

**But no tables showed:**

> python3 manage.py dbshell
> SQLite version 3.21.0 2017-10-24 18:55:49
> Enter ".help" for usage hints.
> sqlite> .tables
> auth_group                  auth_user_user_permissions
> auth_group_permissions      django_admin_log
> auth_permission             django_content_type
> auth_user                   django_migrations
> auth_user_groups            django_session
> sqlite>

**I have tried to delete 1.migration files, 2.pycache, 3.sqlite3.db but working like this every times.**
Please tell my why, and how to create table. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to `delete` both `sqlite3.db` and `migrations` then rerun `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yeah, tried to delete db or record in django_migrations, not work.